# Comparison of `std::chrono` clocks with `boost::xtime`

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, timer

How do the C++11 `std::chrono` clocks `steady_clock` and `high_resolution_clock` compare with `boost::xtime::xtime_get()` in terms of quirks and general properties on various platforms?

The standard does not guarantee that `high_resolution_clock` be steady (it explicitly mentions it may be an alias to `system_clock`), so that's one pitfall to look out for. Other properties that come to my mind:

- **Resolution**: The C++11 standard does not seeem to guarantee any resolution; what are the "real-life" resolutions of these clocks? How does `boost::xtime_get()` fare on the same systems?
- **Maximum Duration**: I know that e.g. `clock()` breaks down after roughly an hour on systems with a 32-bit `clock_t` and a 1 MHz nominal clock resolution. (Yes, I know `clock()` is supposed to do a somewhat different job.) Can the C++11 standard clocks cope with durations in the order of days, maybe even weeks on all known platforms?
- Any other **known issues** or surprising quirks *(Edit: of either `std::chrono` clocks or `boost::xtime::xtime_get`)*?

Comment: Well, one obvious comparison is that one of them is standard while the other is not.

Comment: If you are concerned about the steadiness of a `high_resolution_clock` is has the `is_steady` member which will be `true` if it's steady on the platform.

Comment: This could fill a nice article but it is too broad for an answer here

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Updated the question; the reason I didn't give any examples of boost quirks is that I currently don't know any.

Comment: @user463035818 If you happen to _know_ of any such article, you're welcome to post a link as an answer ;)

Comment: If I knew such an article I could sum up the main points and write an answer, but posting only a link is not considered as a proper answer, anyhow I dont ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do the C++11 std::chrono clocks steady_clock and high_resolution_clock compare with boost::xtime::xtime_get() in terms of quirks and general properties on various platforms?

Any timing library can only deliver what the underlying OS/hardware combination can deliver -- full stop.

Even if the library API promises nanosecond resolution, that doesn't mean that the underlying OS/hardware can deliver that precision.  So ultimately the timing API can not improve upon the quality of the platform.

`boost::xtime` is basically what was standardized by C (and subsequently C++) as `timespec`.  This is a `{second, nanosecond}` pair which is used both as a point in time, and as time duration, depending on the function it is used with in the standard C headers.  Though a quick survey of boost headers appears to use `xtime` only as a time point (I could've missed something).

`timespec` has a long history of existing use, especially in POSIX systems.  It has been in existence on POSIX systems much longer than `std::chrono`, which was designed in 2008, and standardized in C++11 (2011).

The range of `timespec` (`xtime`) is typically larger than the age of the universe.  Though on systems that can not supply a 64 bit integral type, the range of `timespec` will be significantly smaller:  +/-68 years, typically centered around 1970 when it is used as a time point.

As mentioned above, `timespec` *advertises* nanosecond precision on *all* platforms, but will only deliver the precision that the underlying platform can supply.

`chrono` supplies *separate* types for time points and durations.  This helps catch errors at compile time.  For example if you add two time points together, it doesn't compile.  9am today + 7am today is nonsensical.  However if you subtract two time points, that makes perfect sense and returns a separate type:  a duration.  9am today - 7am today is 2 hours.

`chrono` supplies multiple types for both durations and time points which can differ in both precision and representation.  The "built-in" durations are nanoseconds, microseconds, milliseconds, seconds, minutes and hours, each represented with a signed integral type (that list is expanded in the C++20 spec).  But you can create your own duration types with your own precision and representation (e.g. floating point, or a safe-int library).

The implementor of `chrono` for any given platform can advertise the precision of the platforms "`now()`" function.  I.e. it doesn't have to always be nanoseconds, it might be microseconds, or some other unit.  The vendor isn't required to be honest, but they usually are.  Clients can query the return type of `now()` for its precision, programmatically, at compile time (this is C++ after all).

The `chrono` data structures are `{count of units}`, as opposed to the `xtime` `{seconds, nanoseconds}` data structure.  For `chrono` this is true of both durations and time points, even though these are distinct types.

The `{count of units}` layout has several advantages over the  `{seconds, nanoseconds}` layout:

- There is an opportunity to have a smaller `sizeof`.  `system_clock::time_point` is typically 64 bits while `xtime` is typically 128 bits.  This does give `xtime` a superior range.  However the `chrono` library can also be used with 128 bit integral types which will subsequently have a larger range than `xtime`'s.
- Clients can make the size/range tradeoff with `chrono`.  `xtime` clients get what they get.
- Arithmetic is faster/more-efficient and easier to program with the `{count}` data structure than with `{seconds, nanoseconds}`.  This leads to code that is smaller, faster, and generally more bug free (negative values represented with `{seconds, nanoseconds}` are an ongoing horror story).
- For a given `sizeof` and precision, one can always get a larger range with a `{count}` data structure than a multi-field data structure such as `{seconds, nanoseconds}`.

> The standard does not guarantee that high_resolution_clock be steady (it explicitly mentions it may be an alias to system_clock), so that's one pitfall to look out for.

In practice `high_resolution_clock` is always a type alias for either `steady_clock` or `system_clock`.  Which, depends on platform.  My advice is to just use `steady_clock` or `system_clock` so you know what you're dealing with.

> Resolution: The C++11 standard does not seeem to guarantee any resolution; what are the "real-life" resolutions of these clocks?

The *advertised* resolutions are:

```
libc++/llvm:

system_clock
    rep is long long : 64 bits
    period is 1/1,000,000
    is_steady is 0

high_resolution_clock
    rep is long long : 64 bits
    period is 1/1,000,000,000
    is_steady is 1

steady_clock
    rep is long long : 64 bits
    period is 1/1,000,000,000
    is_steady is 1

high_resolution_clock is the same type as steady_clock

libstdc++/gcc:

system_clock
    rep is long : 64 bits
    period is 1/1,000,000,000
    is_steady is 0

high_resolution_clock
    rep is long : 64 bits
    period is 1/1,000,000,000
    is_steady is 0

steady_clock
    rep is long : 64 bits
    period is 1/1,000,000,000
    is_steady is 1

high_resolution_clock is the same type as system_clock

VS-2013:

system_clock
    rep is __int64 : 64 bits
    period is 1/10,000,000
    is_steady is 0

high_resolution_clock
    rep is __int64 : 64 bits
    period is 1/1,000,000,000
    is_steady is 1

steady_clock
    rep is __int64 : 64 bits
    period is 1/1,000,000,000
    is_steady is 1

high_resolution_clock is the same type as steady_clock
```

Because of my opening remarks, the "real-life" resolutions are very likely to be identical to `xtime`'s for any given platform.

> Can the C++11 standard clocks cope with durations in the order of days, maybe even weeks on all known platforms?

Yes.  Even months and years.

The first duration limit you will hit is when dealing with nanosecond resolution.  `chrono` guarantees this will have at least a 64 bit signed integral representation giving you +-292 years of range.  When talking about `system_clock`, this range will be centered on 1970.

> Any other known issues or surprising quirks

When operating at or near range limits, the `chrono` library can easily and silently overflow.  For example if you compare `microseconds::max()` with `nanoseconds::max()`, you will experience an overflow and get an indeterminate result.  This happens because the comparison operator will first convert the `microseconds` to `nanoseconds` before doing the comparison, and that conversion overflows.

Steer well clear of the duration and time_point range limits.   If you have to deal with them, and are not sure how, look on Stackoverflow for answers. Ask a question specific to your concern if that search is not satisfactory.

Comment: Wow, kudos for the detailed answer. - So if I'd need to measure elapsed wall clock time of a piece of code at a precision in the order of milliseconds, but the code may at times run for weeks or even more, then for all practical purposes `std::chrono::steady_clock` would be my standard-compliant portable friend?

Comment: `steady_clock` is a good choice for timing on the order of milliseconds.  But it is less good for timing on the order of weeks.  But it isn't terrible.  `steady_clock` will typically count your platform's hardware clock cycle counter, and convert that into convenient units such as nanoseconds.  But there's no such thing as a perfect clock, and your computer's clock is on the poor side of average.  Your quartz wrist watch will typically loose a second or two a week.  Your computer's clock won't do better and may be worse.

Comment: `system_clock` will ask other clocks on the network what time it is every so often and correct itself.  So it is worse at timing short intervals on the order of milliseconds, but better at timing long intervals on the order of weeks.  Either `steady_clock` or `system_clock` will work.  But each has their strengths and weaknesses.

Answer (score 0):

A few 1st- and 2nd-hand results testing the behaviour of `sleep_for` with a duration of 1 millisecond:

The following platforms tend to "oversleep", at least on average (timed over 1000 iterations):

- Windows Subsystem For Linux / g++ (1.8 ms, apparently overhead)
- Genuine Ubuntu / g++ (1.1 ms)
- FreeBSD / clang (1.1 ms)
- Wingwin / g++ (16 ms, apparently minimum)
- OS X (Darwin) / g++ / POSIX thread model (1.2 ms)

So far, no platform seems to "undersleep" on average.